# Image pixels manipulation, error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to manipulate the pixels of an image but it gives an error :

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()`

This is my code ..

```
                Uri selectedImg = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImg, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
                bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                brightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

                        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); i++) {
                                int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
                                int r = Color.red(p);
                                int b = Color.blue(p);
                                int g = Color.green(p);
                                int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

                                r = r + 100;
                                g = g + 100;
                                b = b = 100;
                                alpha = alpha + 100;

                                operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b));
                            }
                        }
                        image.setImageBitmap(operation);
                    }

                });


            }
        }
```

This is the logcat error :

```
04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example..photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example..photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp, PID: 19366
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1449)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1401)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:95)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19425)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
03-04 20:11:11.076 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 20:11:12.676 19366-19366/com.example.zohair.photoeditingapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19366 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Add the error you're getting in logcat.

Comment: Please post stack trace for your error

Comment: Sorry i m new to Stackoverflow so i might not be placing things in their place

Comment: I guess that 'i' somehow gets bigger or equal to the bitmap or image width. Stepping through with a debugger should be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating same bitmap objects multiple times and set to imageview.

You can use bitmap object multiple times. No need to recreate the object.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
// image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
// BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
// bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

There is no need to get `BitmapDrawable` or `Bitmap` again from `Imageview` as you already have original bitmap in `bmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing i twice via this line...

```
for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); i++) {
```

It should be...

```
for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your loops... the second loop has incremented `i`, but you initialize and use value of `j`. I think this creates the problem.